# Index JSON files in elasticsearch using Python?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a bunch of JSON files(100), which are named as merged_file 1.json, merged_file 2. json and so on.

How do I index all these files into elasticsearch using python(elasticsearch_dsl) ?

I am using this code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Elasticsearch
import json
import os
import sys

es = Elasticsearch()

json_docs =[]

directory = sys.argv[1]

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.json'):
        with open(filename,'r') as open_file:
            json_docs.append(json.load(open_file))

es.bulk("index_name", "type_name", json_docs)
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"one":["some data"],"two":["some other data"],"three":["other data"]}
```

What can I do to make this correct ?

Comment: can you show how jsondocs looks like?

Comment: You're missing the command line before each document. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-bulk) for more details.

Comment: @BhargaviSri - Added

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For this task you should be using `elasticsearch-py` (`pip install elasticsearch`):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import sys, json

es = Elasticsearch()

def load_json(directory):
    " Use a generator, no need to load all in memory"
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('.json'):
            with open(filename,'r') as open_file:
                yield json.load(open_file)

helpers.bulk(es, load_json(sys.argv[1]), index='my-index', doc_type='my-type')
```

Comment: How do I get the id's of the jsons that are indexed ?

Comment: If you care about the ids (elasticsearch will create random ones for you otherwise) just have an `_id` field in you json either directly or maybe put the filename there or something

Comment: This  throws error in the action parameter of bulk.

 """ ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\actions.py in expand_action(data)
     25     # make sure we don't alter the action
     26     data = data.copy()
---> 27     op_type = data.pop("_op_type", "index")
     28     action = {op_type: {}}
     29     for key in (

TypeError: pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)"""