# Trying to load json docs in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43982859/7515189), but I am getting error in the actions parameter of bulk method.
I am able to use `next` to generate array of json objects but when I pass it to `helpers.bulk` I get error.

This is my code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import sys, json
import os

es = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
filename = "path_to_file.json"
def load_json(filename):
#     " Use a generator, no need to load all in memory"
print(filename)
with open(filename,'r') as open_file:
    yield json.load(open_file)`

helpers.bulk(es, load_json(filename), index='cllimaster_test', doc_type='clli_data_test')
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This python (not ES) error would occur if `.pop()` had been called on a `list` instead of a `dict`. I haven't seen your json file but here's your linted code which works perfectly fine:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers
import sys
import json
import os

es = Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")
filename = "path_to_file.json"


def load_json(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as open_file:
        yield json.load(open_file)


helpers.bulk(es, load_json(filename), index='cllimaster_test',
             doc_type='clli_data_test')

print(es.count(index='cllimaster_test'))
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out my json was returning a list, fixed it by adding key at the  beginning of array of json objects. I have new issue of read timeout now, i might post new question if not able to figure that out. Please be on the lookout :)

Comment: My json file: `{rows:[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3}]}`.    Kibana is  considering `rows` as field and storing my objects as nested field.  Thats why I  am getting read timeout coz its considering the whole file as single object within rows.

Comment: extract the rows like so `yield json.load(open_file)['rows']`.

Comment: I had edited the file in Notepad++ , but thanks for the solution.