# Index special JSON file in elasticsearch-py?

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am following this answer [Index JSON files in elasticsearch using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981275/index-json-files-in-elasticsearch-using-python) however my JSON file is still recognized as one single document only.
ElasticSearch creates single fields for every entry as '0.created_at' as seen in Kibana.

My JSON file looks a little bit different. Could this be a problem?
I'm quite new to this...Can anyone help?

My Code:

```
import requests, json, os, sys
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': '9200'}])
directory = '.'


def load_json(directory):
    " Use a generator, no need to load all in memory"
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('mini.json'):
            with open(filename, 'r') as open_file:
                yield json.load(open_file)


helpers.bulk(es, load_json('.'), index='my-index', doc_type='my-type')

res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
print(res.content)
```

**My JSON File**

```
{
    "0": {
        "created_at": "Sat May 09 23:57:13 +0000 2020",
        "id_str": "1259271234912522240",
        "text": "@VitalVegas Not sure if you\u2019ve seen this, but seems relevant\u2014,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": "1259203897538654208",
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": "514487309",
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": "VitalVegas",
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "lang": "en",
        "quoted_status_id_str": "1259178497320185856",
        "hashtags": [],
        "user_mentions": [
            "514487309"
        ],
        "user_id": "23156407",
        "screen_name": "azzabazazz",
        "followers_count": 321,
        "friends_count": 846,
        "favourites_count": 6292,
        "statuses_count": 2895
    },
    "1": {
        "created_at": "Sat May 09 23:57:14 +0000 2020",
        "id_str": "1259271241430695937",
        "text": "RT @GABI6here: #SaturdayThoughts WAKE-UP REMEMBER: Spread word on HouseBill to allow entering our house to test for #coronavirus &gt;SO ban\ud83d\uded1 \ud83d\udc41\u2026",
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "retweet_count": 30,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "lang": "en",
        "quoted_status_id_str": "1259242130062618624",
        "hashtags": [
            "SaturdayThoughts",
            "coronavirus"
        ],
        "user_mentions": [
            "1229162888478150657"
        ],
        "user_id": "756894930270904320",
        "screen_name": "Lily4ever3",
        "followers_count": 23862,
        "friends_count": 23293,
        "favourites_count": 12527,
        "statuses_count": 36183
    }
}
```

Comment: `json.load()` gives a json object. you will need list of jsons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import requests, json, os, sys
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': '9200'}])
directory = '.'


def load_json(directory):
    data = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith('mini.json'):
            with open(filename, 'r') as open_file:
                json_data = json.load(open_file)
                for i,k in enumerate(json_data.keys()):
                    data.append({
                        "_index": "my-index",
                         "_type": "my-type",
                        "_id": i,
                        "_source": json_data[k]
                    })
    return data

helpers.bulk(es, load_json('.'))

res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
print(res.content)
```